# How to make infinite scroll in Vue.js App?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, infinite-scroll

I am making a photo gallery using Vue with Unsplash API.And now I wont to make an infinite scroll for loading images. I have an API like this "https://api.unsplash.com/photos?page=1" and know how to make when I come to the page end get photos from "https://api.unsplash.com/photos?page=2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popular way to achieve it, is to use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

It also exists a good wrapper for vue, [vue-intersect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-intersect).
It will allow you to do something like:

```
<template>
  <intersect @leave="loadMore">
      <img src.... 
  </intersect>
<template>

...

methods: {
     loadMore() {

      //here the api call

    }
```

Comment: How to call API when I get to the end of the page with this vue-intersect ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Instead of firing at the end of page, you should fire when an element leaves or enter the viewport.

Comment: Ty for helping me

Answer (score 0):

your data most be limited data for an ajax request , like pagination (example : a request should have 20 data) and your new data add to data tag